# SharePoint 2010 localisation of links in Webtemplate

Tags: sharepoint, localization

I created a webtemplate (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434313.aspx) in SharePoint and added following localized Navigation Bar to the top the navigation in the onet.xml:

```
<NavBar Name="$Resources:osrvcore,SspAdministrationTopNavBarTitle;" ID="1002">
 <NavBarLink Name="$Resources:osrvcore,HelpText;" Url="default.aspx" />
</NavBar>
```

then I created a web site based on the template and turned the multilanguage on.
The problem is that the navigation bar stays always in one language and is never localised to current language of the website.
If I use the same xml file in the sitetemplate everything works correctly. If I add the navigation nodes programmatically everything works also fine. 
Has someone already had this problem? I want to avoid adding the nodes programmatically because the localisation goes through the whole onet.xml file.

ANSWER:
We created a support case by Microsoft and hopefuly we receive a hotfix for this behavior.  It seems to be a bug in SharePoint. Until then the only option is to delete the navigation from onet.xml and add the navigation nodes programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself. You can find the solution here: http://vojtan.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/multilanguage-in-navigation-using-webtemplate-does-not-work/